# Page Redirection Issue- Cakephp3 using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-3.0

I have a page where I have kept a dropdown where user can switch over languages. I am using theme so I have kept this dropdown on login.ctp page and posting form values to controller's method using Jquery. I have two form elements within login.ctp I don't know but my dropdown form element is not reaching to particular controller instead it is redirecting to login controller.

```
login.ctp
 <form id="locale_form" method="post" action="changeLanguage">
  <div id="language" class="language" align="right">
  Please Select Language
    <select id="languageselect" name="languageselect">
        <option name="select" value="lang">Select A Language</option>
        <option name="en_EN" value="en_EN">English</option>
        <option name="de_DE" value="de_DE">German</option>
    </select>
 </div>
  </form>
<div id="login-page">
        <div class="container">

              <!-- <form class="form-login"> -->
              <?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
            <?= $this->Form->create('',['class'=> 'form-login','id'=>'login_form']) ?>
-----------------Login Form Code----------------
```

Using Jquery onchange I am making switch over languages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("select").change(function(){       
         $("#locale_form").submit();
    });

    </script>
```

My Userscontroller withing that method:

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;


class UsersController extends AppController
{   
 public function changeLanguage()
    {
         /*I18n::locale('de_DE');
         echo "reached here";*/
         print_r($this->request->data());die(); 
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {

            $lang = $this->request->data('languageselect');
            $this->request->session()->write('locale', $lang);
            I18n::locale($lang);
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }

    }
```

I don't know why But my form element with id="locale_form" is not reaching to its action element. I am using Cakephp3 and I don't know where I have messed up.

Comment: Have you given access to the `changeLanguage` function to non-logged-in users? My guess (which you could confirm with the network activity monitor built into Firefox, Chrome, etc.) would be that it is calling changeLanguage, but that's redirecting to the login page due to access restrictions.

Comment: Yes, You are right! I haven't given access to non-logged in users. So it was forcefully redirecting it to log in first. Sorry! if you had given answer I would have upvoted you. but whatever Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Add this method changeLanguage to allow like below.

```
$this->Auth->allow('changeLanguage');
```